# How to retrieve social media title from dynamic link

Tags: android, firebase, parameters, firebase-dynamic-links

Some of you know how and if possible retrieves the title set to social media parameters creating firebase DynamicLink?
To be more precise I would like to get the title that I set using:

```
DynamicLink.SocialMetaTagParameters socialParameters = ...
.setTitle(myTitleString)
...
```

I would like to retrieve it when I receive the Dynamic link in Android app

Thanks